# A tag that is a request for a new tag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I always thought that, whenever people post questions that they are unsure of what to tag their question with, that there should be a tag that would be named "Unsure" or "Replace" or something.

Basically it would mean "I am unsure of what to tag this with" and because of this, other users will see this and can help by re-tagging the question to have proper tags.

This would be incredibly useful because rather than randomly tagging things to seek attention which may or may not result in someone else fixing your tags, it would be more straightforward and other users would fix more tags because it would become simpler.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think it's useful or necessary.

You should be able to find *at least* one tag that categorizes your problem: Either use the programming language or use [algorithm](/questions/tagged/algorithm) or something similar.

If you can't find *at least* one tag, then you probably didn't do your homework for the question anyway (i.e. you're effectively asking "google that for me" or "solve that for me").

If you *can* find *one* tag, then use that and it will *probably* be tagged by helpful editors  if they see a single lonesome tag in an otherwise well-asked question.

[unsure](/questions/tagged/unsure) or [replace](/questions/tagged/replace) would be meta-tags (i.e. they don't have any meaningful information on their own: they can not/should not stand alone).

Comment: touche. I mean if you had multiple tags, and you knew that there was a subject that could be tagged but you didn't know what to tag it as.... I guess.

Answer (score 6):

The problem with these tags is that they are [meta tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) and therefore not useful on Stack Overflow for it's main function of solving people's programming problems.

If you don't know what to tag your question with, perhaps you need to think a bit more on what you are trying to ask. There *should* be enough tags in the system to cover pretty much everything - except if your problem is about something so new no one else has asked a question on the subject before.

If you **really** need a new tag then ask the question and flag it for a moderator to add the tag.